# Not Matching SQL query over 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables that I want to run a unmatched query. Table 1 is my main table, Table 2 and 3 are tables that records get added to everyday.

Now, result needs to show me what I do not yet have in Table 1 (Exception Report)

Now I have written a script, that only queries 2 tables, but its not working correctly. because Table 1 contains 8277436 records and when I execute the script the result is 8620530?????? I went wrong somewhere.

Script  Below

```
Select distinct ID_NUMBER, CLIENT_CODE 
from [KAMLS].[dbo].[Retail]
Left Join [22AE5D15].[dbo].[Documents1]
on [KAMLS].[dbo].[Retail].ID_NUMBER  NOT LIKE '%' + [22AE5D15].[dbo].[Documents1].B61DDE99 + '%'
```

Table 1 [KAMLS].Retail
    ID_Number    Client_Code

```
Table 2 [22AE5D15].Documents1
B61DDE99 = ID Number

Table 3 [22AE5D16].Documents 2
ID_Number
```

Result I'm looking for is all documents in Table 1 [KAMLS].Retail that does not appear in both table 2 and three, and before I forget, why is my script not giving the correct result... I need to learn from my mistakes...

Thank you

Comment: Please fix your question so the table names match both in the query and from one paragraph to the next.  It is hard to follow what you want.  Sample data from the tables, along with desired results can be a big help.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I don't see my mistake in my query or my paragraph? maybe I'm going blind.

Comment: "Table1 is my main table".  `Table1` doesn't appear in any of your queries.  The table names in them are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to my previous answer, this should give you the desired results:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID_NUMBER INT)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID_NUMBER INT)
DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (ID_NUMBER INT)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1),(2),(3)
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES (1),(4),(5)
;

WITH NotInTable2OrTable3 AS
(
    SELECT ID_NUMBER FROM @Table1
    EXCEPT
    (
        SELECT ID_NUMBER FROM @Table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID_NUMBER FROM @Table3
    )
)

SELECT * FROM NotInTable2OrTable3
```

Comment: Hi @mheptinstall, apologies that my question was not clear enough. All I want to see is how many records I still do not have from table 2 and table 3. In other word table 1 has 1,2,3,4,5,6...... table 2 has 1,2,3 and table 3 has 1,4,5.. the result must show me I still don't have any records for ID number 6.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script isn't working for you is because you are comparing each row in Table1 to each row in Table2 and joining every time they are not like eachother.  This isn't very valuable information for your scenario because if you have 'abc' in table1, that's not like '123' or '456' or '789' so you would join 3 records to 'abc' and it doesn't tell you if 'abc' was in the table2 or not.

You can do what you wish in several ways.  The cte posted will work, but I would just use a left join to both tables and take the result where the joins are null.

```
select ID_NUMBER from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
    on t1.ID_NUMBER = t2.ID_NUMBER
left join Table3 t3
    on t1.ID_NUMBER = t3.ID_NUMBER
where t2.ID_NUMBER is null
    and t3.ID_NUMBER is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.  It returns all ids from table2 that don't match an id from table1, plus all ids from table3 that don't match an id from table1.

```
select table2.id from table2
    left join table1 on table1.id=table2.id
    WHERE table1.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
select table3.id from table3
    left join table1 on table1.id=table3.id
    WHERE table1.id IS NULL
```